# Python login web

Tags: python

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

def xueqiuBrower(url,user,passwd):

    login_page='http://xueqiu.com/'
    try:

        cj=cookielib.CookieJar()

        opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')]

        data=urllib.urlencode({'email':user, 'password':passwd})

        opener.open(login_page,data)
        op=opener.open(url)
        data=op.read()
        return data
    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)

if __name__=='__main__':
    url='http://xueqiu.com/'
    name='....'
    passwd='....'
    print xueqiuBrower(url,name,passwd)
```

I use python 2.7 ,i want to login web, but it can't, return "HTTP Error 404: Not Found
None",Please help me to solve it,thanks

Comment: Do you have the option to install 3rd party libraries? If yes, have you tried using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)? It makes HTTP in Python very easy.

Comment: Thank you,i use this code to login another web is OK,but don't login this url,so i want to know why

Comment: Do you have a complete stack-trace of the error? If yes, please edit your question and add it to it.

Comment: The error log is only "HTTP Error 404: Not Found None" ,how to use requests to login?

Comment: The `404` error means that somewhere you access a non-existing URL. It's impossible to say what the error is without stack-trace.

Comment: ... ooooh... I just realised that you swallow the exception. You do `except Exception ... print str(e)`. This is okay but hides important information for debugging. If you look at the complete `try` block, it has "unknowns" (variables) which come from *outside the `try` block*. You should always include those if you print/log the exception.

Comment: At first glance, your code looks correct to me... It is of course possible, that the remote site falsely returns a `404` code. But just in case: Are you *100%* certain that your URL is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong URL. The correct URL to access the login form is:

```
http://xueqiu.com/service/login
```

When you call `opener.open` with the `data` argument, Python will send a `POST` request. However, that does not seem to be allowed on the URL you specified. And the remote site, returns the wrong error code. Instead of `405 Method not allowed`, it returns `404 Not found`.

Inspecting the source code of the page by simply right-clicking the login form and choosing "inspect element", revealed the correct URL.